# How to create a shapefile [polygon type] from a Geodataframe, returned from a Oracle Spatial cursor with geometry column type=cx_Oracle.LOB?

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, geodataframe, cx-oracle

I'm trying to create a shapefile [2D polygon type] with a Geodataframe, that result from a SQL made to a Oracle Spatial database.
The SQL and the Geodataframe creation runs without errors, but when I try to use the GeoDataframe[.to_file] function, returns a few errors in the command:

```
geoparc.to_file('.../out/export.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Am I missing any parameters for the geometry type in .to file function?

How can I set the geometry type in the .to_file function?

geometry data type:

```
print(type(geoparc.geometry[0]))
 = class 'cx_Oracle.LOB'>

print(geoparc.geometry[0]) = 
POLYGON ((225117.58 411950.12, 225057.26803977 411941.365038031, 225058.343749989 411940.968749974, 225057.812500075 411939.468749988))
```

command:

```
geoparc.to_file('.../out/export.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Errors:
 geoparc.to_file('.../out/export.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile');

...Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 413, in to_file to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs);

...Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 106, in to_file    schema = infer_schema(df);

...Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 143, in infer_schema    raise **ValueError("Geometry column cannot contain mutiple "
ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file.**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon'}
```

Then

```
geoparc.to_file('.../out/export.shp', schema=schema, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately the function .to_file return the errors below. Can you know the reason? ...\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 413, in to_file
    to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 110, in to_file
    schema=schema, **kwargs) as colxn:
...\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 396, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
...\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 262, in open
    this_schema['properties'] = OrderedDict(schema['properties'])
KeyError: 'properties'